# Different colorings of bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, bipartite-graphs

Every tree is a bipartite. Can we show, if it is true, that it has only one possible "split" or in other words only 2 possible symmetric vertex colorings (red-blue) ? Is it true for any bipartite graph?

Answer (score 1):

This is true for any (non-empty) connected bipartite graph, or more generally, the number of bicolorings is $2^k$ where $k$ is the number of connected components.

The proof is rather simple: For each connected component you distinguish one vertex which determines the coloring. Once you color the distinguished vertex (two choices), everything else in its connected component is determined.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: You've got 2 choices for *each* vertex, then you need to show they are the same for *all* vertices somehow.

Comment: While at first it seems that any vertex can have any of the two colors, try to think what would happen if we were to color only one vertex per each connected component. What are the possible colors for the neighbors of that distinguished vertex? What are the possible colors for the neighbors of the neighbors? Etc.